# How should I deal with multi-dimensional tensors for nodes in a graph convolution network?

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, geometric-deep-learning, graph-neural-networks

How to work with GCN when the features of each node is not a 1D vector? For example, if the graph has N nodes and each node has features of the form $C \times D \times E$.

Also, is there an open-source implementation for such a case?

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Have you tried to reshape your tensor into a 1D vector of shape $C*D*E$?